# Best way to merge photos from two iCloud accounts and present them via Apple TV?

Tags: iphone, icloud, appletv, photos.app

My and the gf were on holliday and both took pictures with our iPhones. We now wanna select some to show to the family from both accounts and present them via our Apple TV that has me logged in with my account.

What would be the smart way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One create a shared folder, then invite the other.

Then post the pics and invite those you want to see them.

The purpose of shared folders.

Just done it with 7 members of my family - all with different Apple ID's.